# is_dir check is not working

Tags: php, directory

I'm having some problems using / understanding is_dir. (Yes, I have read the PHP doc).

I have a baseDIR as following:

```
$baseDIR = 'I:\Development\wamp\www\mySite\wp-content\uploads\'
```

The following code is TRUE and therefore outputs the text:

```
if (is_dir($gallery->baseDIR)) 
  echo 'DIR exists';
```

Now I need to check if there is a directory called 'f' (yes, just one character). But the following code returns false:

```
if (is_dir($gallery->baseDIR.'f\\')) 
  echo 'DIR exists';
```

Why is this not returning true, when the dir exists?

I'm developing on Win XP, but my ISP prod server is Unix.

**Update:**
Echoing **$gallery->baseDIR.'f\'** gives me the following output:

```
I:\Development\wamp\www\mySite\wp-content\uploads\f\
```

**Update 2:** 
I have to admit that I'm tired after 12h of work and it's way past midnight. Simple STUPID mistake from me. I had forgoten to add he image folder to the base dir....

```
$baseDIR = 'I:\Development\wamp\www\mySite\wp-content\uploads\slgallery\'
```

Comment: First of all, before anything else : did you try echoing $gallery->baseDIR.'f\\' to be absolutly sure it contains what you want ?

Comment: Of course :) Output is: I:\Development\wamp\www\mySite\wp-content\uploads\f\

Comment: @Steven: you might want to add your experiments (echoing `$gallery->baseDIR...`) to your original question, it stops people missing something important in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be an [`open_basedir`](http://www.php.net/features.safe-mode) restriction. Check the setting by executing phpinfo(), this setting is usually present when safe_mode is enabled.

Comment: Does it fail on both development and production? Are the read permissions as they are for other directories that work?

Comment: I haven't gotten as far as testing it on a Unix / Linux server yet. I've just started developing. All dirs are created the same way and has the same permissions.

Comment: I would test it on your linux server. I would even try (as unlikely as it is to be the cause) to create another directory with a longer name. I don't see why this should be broken.

Comment: Ok, I fel dumb now. But I have to blame it on the late ours and 12 hours of working. Your suggestion helped me find the problem. I had forgotten to add one extra folder to the baseDIR. Adding this, and it all works! :) Thanks!

Comment: It happens to the best of us, I guess that's why SO was invented. Glad you found your solution :)